# Posting Session data to Database/Email

Tags: php, forms, session, post, mysqli

I have come up with the below but have an issue with the posting to SQL, can anybody help out/explain how to make it work?

i went down the route of Form - Store details in session - click confirm - Email/Store in database - destroy session.

everything works except for storing into the SQL database.

this is my post to SQL code.

```
<?php include 'config.php'; ?>
<?php
//database connection
$db = new mysqli("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
$db->select_db("$dbname");
?>



<?php
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    //geting the values from user input form index
    $fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
    $lname = $_SESSION['lname'];
    $address1 = $_SESSION['address1'];
    $address2 = $_SESSION['address2'];
    $city = $_SESSION['city'];
    $postcode = $_SESSION['postcode'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $phone = $_SESSION['phone'];
    $charity = $_SESSION['charity'];
    $est_donation = $_SESSION['est_donation'];
    //query
    if ($db->query("INSERT INTO registrant
        (fname,lname,address1,address2,city,postcode,email,phone,charity,est_donation)
        VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$address1','$address2','$city','$postcode','$email','$phone','$charity','$est_donation')"))
        ;
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

//Do we know the customers details?
$fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
$lname = $_SESSION['lname'];

$address1 = $_SESSION['address1'];
$address2 = $_SESSION['address2'];
$city = $_SESSION['city'];
$postcode = $_SESSION['postcode'];

$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$phone = $_SESSION['phone'];
$charity = $_SESSION['charity'];
$est_donation = $_SESSION['est_donation'];
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    </head>

    <body>

        <form action="remember_customer.php" method="post" name="register" id="register">

            First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?php print $fname; ?>"><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="<?php print $lname; ?>"><br>

            Address: <input type="text" name="address1" id="address1" value="<?php print $address1; ?>"><br>
            Address: <input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" value="<?php print $address2; ?>"><br>
            City: <input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="<?php print $city; ?>"><br>
            Postcode: <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" value="<?php print $postcode; ?>"><br>


            E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php print $email; ?>"><br>
            Phone: <input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php print $phone; ?>"><br>
            Charity: <input type="charity" name="charity" id="charity" value="<?php print $charity; ?>"><br>
            Est.Donation: <input type="est_donation" name="est_donation" id="est_donation" value="<?php print $est_donation; ?>"><br>
            <button type="submit" form="register" name="register" id="register">Final - Check</button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**order_confirm.php**

```
<?php
//Start the session
session_start();

//Do we know the customers details?
$fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
$lname = $_SESSION['lname'];

$address1 = $_SESSION['address1'];
$address2 = $_SESSION['address2'];
$city = $_SESSION['city'];
$postcode = $_SESSION['postcode'];

$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$phone = $_SESSION['phone'];
$charity = $_SESSION['charity'];
$est_donation = $_SESSION['est_donation'];

if ($fname == '') {
    header('location:index.php');
    exit();
}
?>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

    <head>

        <title>Registration Form</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Register Order</h1>

        <br><br>
        First Name: <?php print $fname; ?><br>
        last Name: <?php print $lname; ?><br>

        Address: <?php print $address1; ?><br>
        Address: <?php print $address2; ?><br>
        City: <?php print $city; ?><br>
        Post Code: <?php print $postcode; ?>
        Email: <?php print $email; ?><br>
        Phone: <?php print $phone; ?><br>
        Charity: <?php print $charity; ?><br>
        Est. Donation: <?php print $est_donation; ?><br>
        <br><br>
        <a href="email_action.php"><button>Confirm Order</button></a>


    </body>
</html>
```

**email_action.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$sTime = date("dmYHi");

if (isset($_SESSION['fname'])) {
    $fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['lname'])) {
    $lname = $_SESSION['lname'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['address1'])) {
    $address1 = $_SESSION['address1'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['address2'])) {
    $address2 = $_SESSION['address2'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['city'])) {
    $city = $_SESSION['city'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['postcode'])) {
    $postcode = $_SESSION['postcode'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['phone'])) {
    $phone = $_SESSION['phone'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['charity'])) {
    $charity = $_SESSION['charity'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['est_donation'])) {
    $est_donation = $_SESSION['est_donation'];
}


require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('noreply@host.co.uk', 'Registerering Name');
$mail->addAddress($email, $fname);
$mail->AddBCC('info@host.co.uk', ' Registration');

$mail->Subject = 'Registration - Ref# ' . $ref . ' ';

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Body = '<center><h1>Registration Confirmation</h1>

    Thanks for registering, please find comfirmation detials below and payment instructions below.
    <br><br>
    If you need to amend your details please contact us at: email@host.co.uk.</p>

    <h3><u>Registration Details</u></h3>

    <b><span style="color:#ea00ff">Reference#</span></b>' . $ref . ' <br>

    <table width="360">
    <tr>
    <td width=200">
    ' . $fname . '
    ' . $lname . '
    <br>
    ' . $address1 . '<br>
    ' . $address2 . '<br>
    ' . $city . '<br>
    ' . $postcode . '
    <br>
    ' . $email . '<br>
    ' . $phone . '<br>
    ' . $charity . '<br>
    ' . $est_donation . '<br>

    </td>
    <td width="160"><img src="#" width="160" height="115" alt="logo"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    ';


$mail->AltBody = "Hello, my friend! This message uses plain text !";

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Uh-oh.. something bad happened! Check your register form, If it is empty email as at info@host.co.uk to see if we have received it..';
    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Thanks for your order! You will receive a confirmation email shortly with everything you need to know, see you soon!';
}

session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: Please use [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) you are wide open for a MySQL injection attack. [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) has never been more relevant since your attack vector is in the registration fields..

Comment: Besides the prepared statements, your query does not look blatantly wrong.  What does error_log say?  Any error on the INSERT?  What is your table definition?  Have you tried your INSERT directly on the database (not through this PHP to validate it)?

Comment: Also, I see a weird looking `);` at the end of your sql query. might as well debug the error if the query does fail so you will at least know what the error is

Comment: move you query out of the second if statement and use prepared statements